# Device Owner setup using code not working

Tags: android, device-admin, device-owner

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dpm set-device-owner com.integral.kiosk.kioskapp/.receivers.MyDeviceAdminReceiver");

not setting the device owner in Android emulator Nexus 6 OS Android 8.
but when using adb shell command it is working fine.

attaching the code below which i used in oncreate function.

```
 ComponentName deviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, MyDeviceAdminReceiver.class);
        if (!mDevicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(deviceAdmin)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not Device Admin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent activateDeviceAdmin = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
            activateDeviceAdmin.putExtra(
                    DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, deviceAdmin
            );
            activateDeviceAdmin
                    .putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "After activating admin, you will be able to block application uninstallation.”");
            startActivityForResult(activateDeviceAdmin,
                    PM_ACTIVATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }


        if (mDevicePolicyManager.isDeviceOwnerApp(getPackageName())) {
            mDevicePolicyManager.setLockTaskPackages(deviceAdmin, new String[]{getPackageName()});
            Toast.makeText(this, "Device Owner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            startLockTask();
            mDevicePolicyManager.clearDeviceOwnerApp(getPackageName());
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Not Device Owner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dpm set-device-owner com.integral.kiosk.kioskapp/.receivers.MyDeviceAdminReceiver");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, did you get any help for this? I'm also stuck with this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all the "add device admin" code, everything within the first if statement block. Each Android release since Lollipop deprecates more and more device administrator APIs. Your app only needs to be the device owner. Once it is the device owner, it cannot be uninstalled and you can set locked tasks from it such as itself.